# Address search using downloaded map

Tags: here-api

We have the requirement to get the route creation and navigation when the user has no internet but downloaded the map region in which he’d like to have the route and navigation.

So, as an example:

  - I, as a user, have no internet connection, but I have downloaded two states in the USA: California and Nevada;

  - I, as a user, would like to calculate a route from Los Angeles to Las Vegas and use navigator for it.

Our issue is:  
- The user can’t calculate the route even if he has already downloaded needed regions (when there’s no internet connection). The application doesn’t search for location at all.

 
So my question is
- Can this SDK solve our issue at all?
- If yes, can you share some thoughts about why we got this issue?

 
Thank you and will wait for your feedback
Kindly,

**UPDATE**:

Environment: HERE iOS SDK, version 3.13.2, an account is “Freemium”, but credentials are set up as “Premium” 
We are using NMAPlaces - createAutoSuggestionRequest to provide a user with location suggestions as they type. We would like to support this feature in offline mode too. And so we implemented an offline mode, using NMAMapLoader. But while in offline mode, i.e. no internet connection is available, NMAPlaces does not return expected suggestion results.

We have tried setting request.connectivity to offline/online, but it gives the same results as just turning the network off/on.

Comment: Hi Serhii and welcome to SO. You sadly don't mention the platform, nor the SDK (version and variant), nor anything you tried so far, so it's a bit tricky to guess. It would be easier if you add more information: a) which SDK from HERE (I assume, since you added the here-api tag) did you use ? Mobile SDK ? 3.x ? Premium or Starter ? I can tell you already, only HERE SDK 3.x Premium is able to fulfil your requirements above. And what did you try ? What error did you get ? Please add some more details to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco Description Updated

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, as createAutoSuggestionRequest is not supported for offline mode as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAPlaces.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAPlaces(im)createAutoSuggestionRequestWithLocation:partialTerm:) . You could switch to general search with createSuggestionRequestWithLocation:partialTerm  in offline mode for the search function.

[image]